# The power button doesn't work when a KDE session is locked

Tags: fedora, power, hibernate, kde, fedora-15

I've configured (System settings - Power management) the power button to hibernate the system.
This doesn't work when the session is locked (Ctrl + Alt + L).

Is there a way to change that?

I'm on Fedora 15 with KDE, all updates installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine it doesn't respond to them for security reasons, although that's really silly.  If someone can press your power button they could just forcefully shut down your computer rather than hibernate it.

I suggest you [file a wish on KDE's Bugzilla](https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=solid&format=guided).  Maybe they'll add this functionality.